# Loading xml data to google maps

Tags: javascript, maps

I am building a map with some markers, which when clicked open a link.
After some research around here I have something that does what i need.
Not having much experience, I am stack with some changes I would like to make, so any help will be very welcome.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var points = [
  ['prop1', 59.9362384705039, 30.19232525792222, 12, 'https://www.google.com'],
  ['prop2', 59.941412822085645, 30.263564729357767, 11, 'https://www.google.com'],
  ['prop3', 59.939177197629455, 30.273554411974955, 10, 'https://www.google.com']
];
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  var shape = {
    coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var place = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1], place[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      shape: shape,
      title: place[0],
      zIndex: place[3],
      url: place[4]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.open(this.url);

    });
  }
}

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.91823239768787, 30.243222856188822),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
  setMarkers(map, points);
}
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:75%; height:75%">
</body>
</html>
```

So now I am trying to do a couple of things:

1. I would like to call the points variables from an external xml file.
2. My links will look like this: http://www.somefixedlink/someuniquesequence.
   How can it up so i only load from the xml the "someuniquesequence", and the rest of the link is added?

Thank you in advance,
iPanos

Comment: In this instance you're far better off using JSON than XML as you already have the data structure.

Comment: Thank you for this. Since I am not so experienced I am not sure I can do this. Can you kindly share some more info?